# What are these bugs on my kitchen ceiling?

Tags: kitchens, pest-control, insect

I hope someone can help me identify this bug. They are black, really small and have wings.

They are not love bugs, but they are fond of attaching to one another the way love bugs do, and they keep multiplying and coming back no matter how many times you kill them. They limit where they stay to my kitchen,  specifically on the ceiling.

Please help me identity this bug and also give suggestions on how to get rid of them.

The strange insects are on the floor
[image: The strange insects are on the floor here..]

Those are some of the dead insects on the floor
[image: Those are some pf the dead insects on the floor]

Answer (score 1):

"Bugs" means crawly things, which can include insects, arachnids, millipedes, etc. Insects have 6 legs. Most insects have 2 pairs of wings (= 4 in total), some are wingless, and some have only 1 pair (= 2 wings). The insects with 2 wings are the Diptera, which includes the mosquitoes and flies. I can't tell which type of insect you have from the pictures, but they look like some kind of fly.

You want to control them, but despite what the pest control guy might tell you, there is no "fly poison" and a "beetle poison", etc., but just pesticides that will kill all sorts of insects. So you don't have to identify the type of insect in order to apply an insecticide. Whatever insecticide you find at the garden store will work.

If they keep reappearing, it means that they are either finding a way into your house, or that somewhere females laid eggs some time ago (depends on the species, 1-3 weeks ago), and now the adults are coming out in waves. You can apply all of the insecticide in the world, but until you find how they are getting into the house and/or where the eggs were laid, the problem won't go away.

Do a deep cleaning of the kitchen, and make sure the garbage containers are closed with a tight lid. Then make sure that there are no points of entry into the house.

Comment: Even better, take out the trash and give the garbage can a good scrubbing. (No implication that the garbage is over full and spilling everywhere, only that the eggs could be in the current bag of garbage or that something may have spilled out of a bag and into the can.)

Comment: Can't tell from photo, but the most common suspect would be fruit flies. If so, then yes, eliminating access to food for their larvae would be the single biggest step to eliminating the infestation. Keep sink clean, keep trash (and compost bucket if you use one) sealed and empty them regularly. If you're sufficient annoyed, hunting them with a vacuum cleaner hose may help cut the population and lets you vent your frustrations